# How can we redirect from one page to another page on click using anchor without changing the url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can any one help me to solve my problem. I am trying to redirect one page to another page without changing the url but I am not getting success. Can any one help me to find the solution, How can we redirect the page from one page to another without changing the url. Here is the example (Click on No thanks anchor)

http://jennpike.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to put both pages on the same url, then use Javascript to hide/show each part of the page. This would be similar to a lightbox.

You can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

Or even easier, using jQuery here: https://api.jquery.com/hide/ , and https://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Hi Friend, its not answer of my question. If i want put both page on same place and use hide or show than i can but i don't want to use hide and show on it. If you know the answer then please tell me otherwise don't downgrade it.